# Jenkins Android Build Error: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception

Tags: java, android, jenkins, gradle, continuous-integration

I have been trying to do CI using Jenkins for my Android application. I am new to this. After following some of the tutorials, I am able to atleast set up and run the build now option. It download every pom required but while building it give below error.

============================================
C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\e796469c387c11565d873216f24c3b6f\res\drawable\abc_ic_go_search_api_material.xml: error: file not found.
C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\play-services-base-15.0.1.aar\7207fbd3bdb6cb696445cfc77c16e5ed\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\googleg_standard_color_18.png: error: file not found.
C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\e796469c387c11565d873216f24c3b6f\res\layout\select_dialog_singlechoice_material.xml: error: file not found.
Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
:app:mergeDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

  > Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

======================================================

Can you please let me know how to resolve it?
Do let me know if anything else is required.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the path is too long. Try this:

1. Jenkins --> Project --> Project Configuration --> Build
2. Select advanced option
3. Check the option box "Force GRADLE_USER_HOME to use workspace"
   [image]
4. Build your project

I solved my problem by this way, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your android gradle plugin version to 3.2.0-alpha12 or newer. AAPT2's version included in these versions contains many fixes for path support on Windows which resulted in similar errors.

Answer (score 0):

you can solve this by separating into smaller group of task
make separate invoke gradle script under build tab

1. clean build assembleDebug
2. test
3. connectedAndroidTest

i had similar issues, when i ran assembleDebug and test together in Jenkins as a single task

Answer (score 0):

When using Jenkins with Window to build Android, I face this problem myself.
I fix by add **GRADLE_USER_HOME** to Environment Variable:

```
GRADLE_USER_HOME = C:\Users\*MyUserName*\.gradle
```

hope this help,